# How to create <div> with several children in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I created a **div** with a class name of **div class = "postWindow"**.

html:

```
<div class = "postWindow">
    <div class = "userName">Initial Name</div>
    <div class = "postTitle">Init title</div>
</div>
```

Now, what I am trying to achieve is that I can create upto 10 of these in a single html window. (upto because the amount of posts may vary from 1-10 and the amount is dynamic)

I tried using the `appendChild()` method but realized it only populated the **div** as the new element. It did not create a new **postWindow**

My .js file has the following function:

```
function createPost(){
    var count = 0;
    while(count < upLimit){
         $.ajax({
            url: root + '/posts/'+curr,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(response){
                 postJson = response;
                 //im lost here     
        }
   });
   count++;

}
```

Using **console.log** my Json response is something like this

```
0: Object
title: "First post"
body: "This is a post"
id: 1
userId: 27
.
.
.
100: //same format of data as object 0
```

Any help would be appreciated! :D

Comment: `$(".postWindow").parent().append("<div class='postWindow'><div class='userName'>Initial Name</div><div class='postTitle'>Init title</div></div>");`

Comment: How does your JSON `response` look like? It will be helpful to add it to  the question.

Comment: So what is parent container of these postWindows? What does data look like?

Comment: the parent container is simply <div class = "pageBottom" id = "bottom">

Comment: Looks like you have the properties in your response object. Call them like you would guess... `response.title` `response.body` etc.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a simple fiddle to demonstrate the above: https://jsfiddle.net/LLceoLwg/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class = "postWindow">
    <div class = "userName">Initial Name</div>
    <div class = "postTitle">Init title</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
      $(".postWindow").parent().append("<div class='postWindow'><div class='userName'>Initial Name</div><div class='postTitle'>Init title</div></div>");
    }               
});
```

Comment: why would you not just append to the parent and go through such a convoluted route?

Comment: My answer was modeled from the OP's code before he apparently changed it. I don't see any comments about why it was changed so idk...i have to agree though, it looks pretty odd since he changed the OP

Comment: sorry im fairly new to javascripting, but how do i replace "init Title" with the one from the json. or any form of var? sorry for being primitive

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my answer. If he's making the ajax calls in a loop, adding the posts from each response in the loop will work perfectly.

Comment: yes it works, but it's a stupid way to program. You could easily just change the selector to `$(".container")`. But if you're adamant on being satisfied with just having it work, then I wish you the best at maintaining your own code.

Comment: And I hope you find someone to give you a hug after your no good,very bad day, champ.

Comment: This is bad. Every time you call `append` will trigger a reflow of the DOM, and you want the smallest number of those for performance. You should be collecting all of the elements into an array and appending them once.

Comment: I can see that, but for a case where each iteration through is making an ajax call, if the upper limit is high, you may be waiting a while before any of the items appear. Buffering them in chunks is probably best. And for a low limit (10) you're absolutely right.

Comment: Making ajax calls in a loop is even worse, tbh. But that is not really the focus of the question.